# Event for zoomed in or zoomed out

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there any event to check if user end zoomed in a map or end zoomed out the map

What we do is.. we want to send the latitude or longtitude to server when they making change to the map. for example when they end dragging we will send the latitude and longtitude to server to load some shop location that are within boundary of that latitude and longtitude and we will put the pins on it. so all the possible event are user dragging map, zoom in, zoom out and scrolling. we will not use bounds_changed event because it will send data to the server all the time.

```
    //Get bound of the map when a user dragged the map.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
        bound = map.getBounds();
        var latlng_NE = bound.getNorthEast();
        var latlng_SW = bound.getSouthWest();

       // Some code to send latitude or longtitude to server here
       throw new Error(latlng_NE, latlng_SW);
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean: The user can zoom, drag, scroll etc. all action the change the center of the map, you will react by sending message to server, but only after *ALL* of the changes were made, so you do not send a message after every single step, but only after the complex actions have taken place?

Comment: Yes so that we will not send the action so often.. maybe if user action is stop by 3 seconds for scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Google Maps API doc

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    setTimeout(moveToDarwin, 3000);
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events;

---

### edit

```
// closure
(function() {

    var timeout = null;
    var delay = 500;

    function react() {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(react, delay)
    }

    function sendBoundsToServer() {
        bound = map.getBounds();
        var latlng_NE = bound.getNorthEast();
        var latlng_SW = bound.getSouthWest();            
        // some AJAX action to send bound to server
        // ...
    }
    //Action after a user dragged the map.
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
       // Some code to send latitude or longtitude to server here
       setTimeout(sendMessageToServer, 1000)
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
       // Some code to send latitude or longtitude to server here
       setTimeout(react, 1000)
    });


    // Add more events here like the two above  


}())
```

Comment: I can't really get, what you are trying?

Comment: getting zoom out event.. it works already but i wonder why we need to delay it for 3 seconds ?

Comment: This is just the example from the API page